# How to open a page using Captive Network Assistant?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I am developing a captive portal. I would like to have a way to test the remote URL using `/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app` without connecting to an SSID.

Is there a command line that I could use to open `Captive Network Assistant.app` for a particular URL?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this forum. If you know some basic html and understand the terminology, you might be able to change the url. 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to open a specific URL using Captive Network Assistant application.

Comment: Oh I see. I've done research on this before, and I've not had any luck with doing it.